# How do I set password options in Aspnet Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-identity

I have followed the [SO example code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39826998/521554) and the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) but however I change the password length in my Aspnet core 2.1 project nothing changes.
I always get the message "The Password must be at least 6 and at max 100 characters long."

In `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` I have tried

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
  options.Password.RequiredLength = 1;
});
```

in various places, or adding it to `AddDefaultIdentity<>`

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options =>
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 1;
  )
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

but to no avail.

I am using the [non-scaffolded version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50802781/where-are-the-login-and-register-pages-in-an-aspnet-core-scaffolded-app) so I don't have access to the HTML or cshtml files.

Comment: Nothing has changed in this regard. The code you've posted is fine. What is the exact issue you're having?

Comment: As @KirkLarkin noted, the password length is separately enforced by the models of some Razor Pages in the default UI. If you want to reduce the length requirement, you have no choice but to scaffold at least these pages into your project and customize the page models accordingly.

Comment: Have you tried the `Manage Nuget Packages’ `
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/01/06/implementing-custom-password-policy-using-asp-net-identity/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you've found a <strike>bug</strike> reason to scaffold. In the Razor Class Library that contains the Razor Pages implementation of the ASP.NET Core Identity UI, there's an [`InputModel`](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/release/2.1/src/UI/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Register.cshtml.cs#L26) class for the `Register` Page that looks like this:

```
public class InputModel
{
    ...

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

It's clear from this code snippet that no matter what you set `RequiredLength` to, the built-in `ModelState` validation will always require a length of between 6 and 100 characters.

It's also worth noting that this doesn't just affect the `Register` page - I've confirmed that it also affects `ResetPassword`, `SetPassword` and `ChangePassword`.

In terms of a solution: [Chris Pratt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/654031) has pointed out in the comments that the only real way to resolve this is to scaffold the affected pages and make the necessary changes to the `StringLength` attributes.

---

Update: The [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/2091) you've raised has been closed as a duplicate, with the solution being to scaffold the Pages and make the required change.

Answer (score 2):

These are all the option for the password:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.2

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    // Default Password settings.
    options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
    options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;
});
```

To modify the rule see this
[How override ASP.NET Core Identity's password policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39825634/how-override-asp-net-core-identitys-password-policy)
https://andrewlock.net/creating-custom-password-validators-for-asp-net-core-identity-2/

**Update**

You can use  `PasswordValidator` and you can see how to [customize the password policy in ASP.Net identity](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/how-to-customize-password-policy-in-Asp-Net-identity/)

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
  {
           public ApplicationUserManager(): base(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()))
           {
                 PasswordValidator = new MinimumLengthValidator (6);
           }
   }
```

Comment: This doesn't  answer the question. As a matter of fact, OP did try this (and posted it) and is looking for an alternative to set passwords with less than 6 chars, as the options doesn't work for such cases.

Comment: See the question and you can find that it support `ASP.NET Core 2.1, 1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 2.2, 3.0, 3.1, 5.0` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.passwordoptions.requiredlength?view=aspnetcore-5.0,

Comment: I already updated it, and I hope that helps.

Comment: It does help, much appreciated. With a custom class makes it much clear.