# How to disable Password Validation in Razor?

Tags: c#, razor, passwords

I do not want to use any password validation for the user. I want to be able to enter simple passwords without verifying that the password has 6 characters, at least one capital letter, etc.

When I try to change the password using this code, I always get an error if the password does not match the password validator requirement.

```
if (objUser.PasswordHash != passwordHash)
{
    var resetToken = await _UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
    var passworduser =                        
        await _UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(
        user,
        resetToken,
        objUser.PasswordHash);
}
```

Is there any way to disable or change password validation settings?

Comment: Check if this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39825634/how-override-asp-net-core-identitys-password-policy

Comment: Thank you! I found the solution in your link.