# ASP.NET Core how to block specific passwords

Tags: asp.net-core

I have the following code I modified from the original ASP.NET Core project template

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(
        options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
        }
    )
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

But how do I make ASP.NET Core return an error for specific passwords?

Let's say I have an array of banned passwords like this:

```
var bannedPasswords = new[] {"password", "qwertyuiop", "12345678"};
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61913072/529282

Comment: https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2017/01/12/checking-passwords-against-a-dictionary-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: You can try to use [`IPasswordValidator<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.passwordvalidator-1?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to custom your own password validator